# Switch between child Component having same path using v-breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have one main Component in which other small Components are imported.How to switch between these small componets using v-breadcrumbs(vuetify)???

Comment: Please share some reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

Since breadcrumbs semantically should shadow your path, you should probably make use of [tabs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/) (`v-tabs`) to do what you require.

[Here's a good example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs/#grow).

---

In general:

```js
<template>
    <v-tabs
      v-model="tab"
      background-color="transparent"
      color="basil"
      grow
    >
      <v-tab
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item"
      >
        {{ item }}
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>

    <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
      <v-tab-item
        v-for="item in items"
        :key="item"
      >
        <v-card
          color="basil"
          flat
        >
          <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs-items>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        tab: null,
        items: [
          'Appetizers', 'Entrees', 'Deserts', 'Cocktails',
        ],
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```